# How can I fix my worlds not saving?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft PE. I made a cool world with good items and a nice house. I had to leave for school, but when I got home I got on my tablet and played Minecraft, my world was not there. Now every time I make a world and get off Minecraft, it is not there. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a "fix" to your worlds not saving. Just make sure press "Quit to title" before closing the game to make sure it saves the world. Every now and then, the game saves itself but you can never be sure when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you press "Save and quit" and the properly close out the application.

If you are on an android, press the back button until it asks you if you want to quit. If you are on an iOS device, double tap the home button, press and hold the Minecraft PE icon and then press the red X.